# Mysql query to select a column with only alphabetical characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to display records from mysql database where a particular column has only alphabets.

eg,

Table Name: data

```
 column
 abcde
 12345
 xyz
 123
```

so the output should be abcde and xyz only.
So far i tried using pattern match but no luck

here is what is use yet
   `SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Zip LIKE '[^a-zA-Z]'`

Comment: Any reason you're mixing data types?

Comment: I am using text as datatype. but i now want only to display alphabets only. is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Zip REGEXP  '^[A-z]+$'
```

Comment: No, it is not good because in ASCII there are some chars [ \ ] ^_ ` between Z and a "select 'Try' regexp '^[A-z]+$', 'Tr1y' regexp '^[A-z]+$'  , 'Tr[y' regexp '^[A-z]+$';"  returns 1, 0, 1 it should return 1, 0, 0

Answer (score 2):

Try regexp:

```
SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Zip REGEXP '^[a-zA-Z.]+$'
```

Comment: Your solution works (not like the  other answer Zip REGEXP  '^[A-z]+$')

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code too

```
SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Zip NOT  LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use RLIKE for regular expressions: `SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Zip RLIKE '[^a-zA-Z]*$'`.

Also, the "^" in your regex negates the class pattern.  If you are trying to use it as a "front-of-line" anchor, it's in the wrong place, and your regex is returning anything that has something besides `a-zA-Z` in the zip.  If you want entries that are only alpha, move the "^" outside of the square braces:   `SELECT * FROM listing WHERE Zip RLIKE '^[a-zA-Z]*$'`

Comment: @lreeder it gives numeric rows insted of alphabets

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys,  couple of typos there that have been fixed now.  Sometimes you shoot yourself in the foot trying to be the fastest gun.